# MySQL syntax exception, working manually

Tags: java, mysql

I'm using this query manually and it works fine, what I'm missing? If I don't use WHERE, it executes perfectly.

```
for (ArrayList<String> match : matches) {
    System.out.println(match.get(0));

    // String
    // 7412095225787794836

    String query1 = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `matches_players` WHERE `match_id` = ?";
    PreparedStatement preparedStmt1 = (PreparedStatement) conn.prepareStatement(query1);
    preparedStmt1.setString(1, match.get(0));
    ResultSet rs1 = preparedStmt1.executeQuery(query1);
    // You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your    
    // MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?' at line 1

    while (rs1.next()) {
        System.out.println("players=" + rs1.getInt("COUNT(*)"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Does the `match_id` column have `INT` type? Can you try `preparedStmt1.setInt(1, match.get(0).intValue());`

Comment: @OllieJones It's a string. I know, that's stupid. But it comes from a ArrayList<String>.

Comment: Sometime integers are returned as strings, depending on the driver used. Can you see the DDL for the field match_id? I can bet it is integer.

Comment: @AntoanMilkov Using preparedStmt1.setString(1, "test") I get the same error, column type is VARCHAR.

Comment: You should ALWAYS post the full stack trace of an exception when asking about it.

Comment: @JBNizet I'm sorry, I thought it wasn't relevant.

Comment: @MiguelRipoll you should let us decide if it's relevant or not. In that case, the message probably contains something like "syntax error near ?", which would have helped understanding that the query wasn't prepared but executed as is.

Comment: @JBNizet That's what I did. That exception appears on my question code after executeQuery.

Comment: OK. I missed that, sorry. But it's still less clear as a stack trace: we don't have the context, and given that it's a code comment, syntax-highlighted as such, my eyes automatically skip it as irrelevant, although that should be the most important part of your question.

Comment: No problem, will do this next time, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think the `executeQuery` method takes an argument. The SQL text has already been supplied in the prepare. Try removing the argument from the `executeQuery` method.

Replace this:

```
 ResultSet rs1 = preparedStmt1.executeQuery(query1);
                                            ^^^^^^
```

With this:

```
 ResultSet rs1 = preparedStmt1.executeQuery();
```

And see how big a smoke ball that makes.